# Incorrect result of bash shell script

Tags: shell, solaris

If I add this line to end of the script it is working fine. but I want to add this line between a script & if I press n then it should continue the further script till the end:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'want to run Gather [y n]?'  
read response   
[ "$response" = "y" ] || exit;  
cd /var/tmp/  
./gather.sh
```

Comment: If i add this line to end of the script it is working fine. but i want to add this line between a script & if i press n then it should continue the further script till the end

Comment: Use == instead of = and try

Comment: Which result do you get, and what did you expect it to do? Please update your question.

Comment: `==` and `=` are the same operator where `==` is accepted for testing equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you call exit whenever $response is not "y":

```
[ "$response" = "y" ] || exit;
```

To selectively execute some statements based on a condition, use the if-statement:

```
 if [ "$response" == "y" ] ; then
     cd /var/tmp/  
     ./gather.sh
 fi
 echo "continuing ..."
```

This will continue with echoing "continuing ..." even when not entering "y".